# What is analogue of Objective C static variable in Swift?

Tags: swift

It was very convenient to have static variables in Objective C (**static variable's value is maintained throughout all function/method calls**), however I couldn't find anything like this in Swift.

Is there anything like this?

This is an example of static variable in C:

```
void func() {
    static int x = 0; 
    /* x is initialized only once across four calls of func() and
      the variable will get incremented four 
      times after these calls. The final value of x will be 4. */
    x++;
    printf("%d\n", x); // outputs the value of x
}

int main() { //int argc, char *argv[] inside the main is optional in the particular program
    func(); // prints 1
    func(); // prints 2
    func(); // prints 3
    func(); // prints 4
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Static properties in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26567480/static-properties-in-swift)

Comment: @santiago It's not. Static keyword in Objective C and Swift have absolutely different meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After seeing your updated answer, here is the modification for your Objective-C code:

```
func staticFunc() {    
    struct myStruct {
        static var x = 0
    }

    myStruct.x++
    println("Static Value of x: \(myStruct.x)");
}
```

Call is anywhere in your class

```
staticFunc() //Static Value of x: 1
staticFunc() //Static Value of x: 2
staticFunc() //Static Value of x: 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare the variable at the top level of a file (outside any classes) which is called global variable.

> variables at the top level of a file are initialised lazily! So you
>   can set the default value for your variable to be the result of
>   reading the file, and the file won't actually be read until your code
>   first asks for the variable's value.

Reference from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522264/shared-or-static-variable-in-swift).

**UPDATE:**

From your C example you can achieve same thing in swift this way:

```
var x = 0   //this is global variable 

func staticVar() {
    x++
    println(x)
}

staticVar()
x                //1
staticVar()
x                //2
staticVar()
x                //3
```

Tested with playground.

From [Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html):

> In C and Objective-C, you define static constants and variables
>   associated with a type as global static variables. In Swift, however,
>   type properties are written as part of the type’s definition, within
>   the type’s outer curly braces, and each type property is explicitly
>   scoped to the type it supports.
>
> You define type properties with the static keyword. For computed type
>   properties for class types, you can use the class keyword instead to
>   allow subclasses to override the superclass’s implementation. The
>   example below shows the syntax for stored and computed type
>   properties:

```
struct SomeStructure {
static var storedTypeProperty = "Some value."
static var computedTypeProperty: Int {
    // return an Int value here
    }
}
enum SomeEnumeration {
    static var storedTypeProperty = "Some value."
    static var computedTypeProperty: Int {
        // return an Int value here
    }
}
class SomeClass {
    static var storedTypeProperty = "Some value."
    static var computedTypeProperty: Int {
        // return an Int value here
    }
    class var overrideableComputedTypeProperty: Int {
        // return an Int value here
    }
}
```

> **NOTE**
>
> The computed type property examples above are for read-only computed type >properties, but you can also define read-write computed
>   type properties with the same syntax as for computed instance
>   properties.